# Weird issue with changing view background color

Tags: android

I have a bunch of views with solid-colored backgrounds. These views can be dragged around; I would like to change the background depending on whether or not a view intersects with another view. Below is the code I'm using in `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP`

```
// Get all children of the parent view
for(int i = 0; i < ((ViewGroup) getParent()).getChildCount(); i++) {
    View childOne = ((ViewGroup) getParent()).getChildAt(i);
    // For each child, check for intersection with siblings
    for(int z = 0; z < ((ViewGroup) getParent()).getChildCount(); z++) {
        View childTwo = ((ViewGroup) getParent()).getChildAt(z);
        if(childOne == childTwo)
            continue;
        Rect recOne = new Rect();
        childOne.getHitRect(recOne);
        Rect recTwo = new Rect();
        childTwo.getHitRect(recTwo);
        if (Rect.intersects(recOne, recTwo)) {
            ((EditView) childTwo).setPaintColor(Color.RED);
        } else {
            ((EditView) childTwo).setPaintColor(Color.GREEN);
        }
    }
}
```

This should loop through each view and check if the view intersects with another view. If so, change the background color of the intersecting view. All views extend the `EditView` class, which handles its own touch events. I should also mention that `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` brings the touched to the "front", so the user can easily manipulate it if it's hidden behind another view. Below explains how it currently works:

[image: example]

These views are laid out using `RelativeLayout`. I'm beginning to think that the ordering of the views may be the cause of this, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, you need to modify your `for` loop slightly. The reason is because if `childOne` intersects with `childTwo`, it means that `childTwo` also intersects with `childOne`, (so there's no need to check twice). And since both views intersect, I would change the colors of both views at the same time. So I would modify your code this way:

```
// Get all children of the parent view
for(int i = 0; i < ((ViewGroup) getParent()).getChildCount(); i++) {
    View childOne = ((ViewGroup) getParent()).getChildAt(i);
    // For each child, check for intersection with siblings
    // start z at index (i+1)
    for(int z = i+1; z < ((ViewGroup) getParent()).getChildCount(); z++) {
        View childTwo = ((ViewGroup) getParent()).getChildAt(z);
        Rect recOne = new Rect();
        childOne.getHitRect(recOne);
        Rect recTwo = new Rect();
        childTwo.getHitRect(recTwo);
        if (Rect.intersects(recOne, recTwo)) {
            // both views intersect, change both to red
            ((EditView) childOne).setPaintColor(Color.RED);
            ((EditView) childTwo).setPaintColor(Color.RED);
        } else {
            // both views do not intersect, change both to green
            ((EditView) childOne).setPaintColor(Color.GREEN);
            ((EditView) childTwo).setPaintColor(Color.GREEN);
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I believe I've figured out the issue as well. When looping through the views, if a view doesn't intersect a view, it will be changed to green regardless if whether or not it already intersects with another view. I'll need to find a way around this.

Comment: @Raggeth I actually didn't consider the case you just mentioned.